# Joining branches to leaves shows only one UV map at a time. How to get both to show?

Tags: rendering

I have followed a tutorial and made a tree. But when I join the branches and the leaves only one of the UV maps will show at a time.
I have tried everything I can think of but I simply cant find the problem.

Comment: A bit more detail is required for us to have any hope of answering.  How did you make the tree, what tutorial, how did you uv unwrap?  Etc.  But, IF you happened to use the sapling generator, check the UV Maps section under the "Data" tab of the Properties window, you may find two separate UV maps are there, each of which can be viewed/used as needed.

Comment: I did use the sapling generator. There are 2 uv maps. the Tutorial was CG Geek how to create a forest in Blender. I unwrapped the tree branches with smart uv project. But the leaves were not unwrapped they are stacked together over the leaf. When I select the camera icon beside the uv maps in object data. It shows the one selected. But the other will not show. If I select the other the opposite happens.

Comment: So How do I get both uv maps to show at the same time?

Comment: If UV maps for different objects are called the same after joining they will be converted into one UV map with all UV islands there. If UV maps for the objects are called in a different way they will be added as different maps to the joined object. That's all

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated you used the Sapling generator and there are two UV maps: to view the complete UV maps you are going to need to make sure that all of your vertices are selected (type A once or twice until everything is orange).  The camera icon under "UV Maps" is important, it shows which UV map is "active" for display and editing, but it does not control which UV map you are **viewing.**  To view a particular UV map, make sure it is highlighted (i.e. click on the name of the UV Map or the little ball icon to the left of it, use the arrow keys, etc.).

It's beyond the scope of your question (and this answer), but you may well wish to set up separate materials for your leaves and branches, and also separate vertex groups to facilitate selecting/deselecting them.  I will however share a trick, if you did not create the vertex groups before you joined the meshes: If you have the Leaf UV map active, and you click the "Keep uv and edit mode selection in sync" button in the toolbar of the UVImage Editor window, and you deselect all, and then you box select the leaf UV faces in the UVImage Editor window (type B then drag to select), that should select just the leaves.  You can then assign them to a vertex group, then invert the selection to create a trunk/branch vertex group.

Once you have separate vertex groups, that will make it easier to assign each group to a separate material if you wish.  That is starting to get into tutorial territory however.

Regarding your followup query, you might wish to have a single material and UV map for the leaves and trunk/branches if, for example, you're going to use the tree as a game asset, but for other usage cases it may be easier and more convenient to keep the two UV maps separate.  That way you do not have to manage the UV islands and texture space.  Creating the combined UV map is not hard, if you have the branch/trunk UV map active, and you select all the leaves using the leaf vertex group you created, and unwrap them, they will be unwrapped to the active UV map.  Indeed you might find that they are unwrapped there already.  But then you'll need to arrange them in the UV map to an area that doesn't overlap the trunk/branch faces, and that is definitely beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The separate uv images would be fine for my use. I am not getting any results tonight. I will try again in the morning. I think I may start new. Make the vertex groups assigned to materials.

Comment: Good luck!  There's a lot to take in at first and I think I've seen the tutorial you're talking about, it breezes over a few concepts.  You'll get there however.